# socket io server running on port 90 - AWS ec2 - security group port is open - yet can't connect

Tags: node.js, sockets, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a running nodejs based socket.io server on AWS ec2, this server is running on port 90, and i can run the local tests on this server at the same port.

netstat -a shows me the port 90 as open as well for connections

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:3001          *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:90                    *:*                     LISTEN
```

I can vouch for the fact that I have the port 90 open on my security group settings, yet I can not connect at the port 90 to my server.
I am not doing anything as foolish as making my clients connect over the localhost.

I have tried telnet to my server at the port 90 but it doesn't work

I have port 22 and 80 open as well and I can very well telnet to them.

Comment: What error do you get when you telnet to IP:90 from outside the server?  Connection Refused or a Timeout?

Comment: it works now, it was giving connection timeout, it seems like it took ages for the security group changes to take effect.

Comment: Mine was because there was a problem with underlying mongod instance. It is not ready by the time node starts and node takes time to reveal the fact + env variables were not set properly